# How to use ICDeviceBrowser - does not find camera

Tags: swift, macos, camera

I've just started to use ImageCaptureCore and ICDeviceBrowser to begin development of a camera control software and it runs ok but does not find anything.

I've tried it on 3 different cameras (in PTP mode and MSC mode) including an iPhone. I have the latest MacOS and Xcode.

The delegate is never called and the device array is always empty.

```
import Foundation
import ImageCaptureCore

print("Hello, World!")

let browser = ICDeviceBrowser.init()
let myDeviceBrowserDelegate = myDeviceBrowserDelegateClass.init()
browser.delegate = myDeviceBrowserDelegate
browser.browsedDeviceTypeMask = ICDeviceTypeMask(rawValue: ICDeviceTypeMask.camera.rawValue | ICDeviceLocationTypeMask.local.rawValue | ICDeviceLocationTypeMask.bluetooth.rawValue | ICDeviceLocationTypeMask.bonjour.rawValue | ICDeviceLocationTypeMask.remote.rawValue | ICDeviceLocationTypeMask.shared.rawValue)!

browser.start()
while(browser.isBrowsing){
    print("browsing cameras...")
    print(browser.devices!)
    sleep(10)
}
browser.stop()
```

Here is the delegate:

```
import Foundation
import ImageCaptureCore

class myDeviceBrowserDelegateClass : NSObject, ICDeviceBrowserDelegate {
    func deviceBrowser(_ browser: ICDeviceBrowser, didAdd device: ICDevice, moreComing: Bool) {
        print("Device added = \(device) and more coming = \(moreComing)")
    }

    func deviceBrowser(_ browser: ICDeviceBrowser, didRemove device: ICDevice, moreGoing: Bool) {
        print("Device added = \(device) and more going = \(moreGoing)")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I needed to execute a runloop. Since Xcode tools incorporate a runloop automatically, I just had to run it rather than a wait loop

```
RunLoop.current.run(until: Date.init(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1))
```

Comment: Can you provide this line in context? I'm getting the same problem and adding this line doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine.

```swift
browser.start()
while(browser.isBrowsing){
    print("browsing cameras...")
    print(browser.devices!)
    RunLoop.current.run(until: Date.init(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1))
}
browser.stop()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).